# how to add Google Calendar in android

Tags: android, user-interface, calendar, google-api, android-gui

I am trying to add Google calendar which look like as below attached diagram. Is there any way to add this calendar in my android ? I am new to android Help me to solve this.

[image: **Google Calendar**]

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

Comment: I am looking for the calendar which I have shown above and I know its possible but somehow I am not able to find it. Still thanks for your help @NaveenTamrakar

Comment: Just go through this link you will get your answer - https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Google/Calendar/

Comment: Please do through this link:- [http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/calenderview-example/][1]